# TextViews inside GridLayout are being cut off on the right side Android

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-gridlayout

I have a GridLayout like this

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:elevation="2dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:text="Famous People"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <GridLayout
                            android:id="@+id/llFamousPeople"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:columnCount="3"
                            android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:textSize="17sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

I am setting the values inside GridLayout programmatically like this

```
extra?.famous_people?.forEach {
            val textView = TextView(this)
            val gridparams = GridLayout.LayoutParams()
            gridparams.apply {
                height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            }
            textView.layoutParams = gridparams
            val marginParams = textView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
            marginParams.bottomMargin = 10
            marginParams.topMargin = 10
            marginParams.leftMargin = 10
            marginParams.rightMargin = 10
            textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5)
            textView.text = it
            llFamousPeople.addView(textView)
        }
```

And the resulting view appears like this
[image]

The names on the 3rd column are being cut off. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Can you try recyclerview GridLayoutManager**

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView    
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:elevation="2dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:text="Famous People"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rc_txt_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                       app:spanCount="3"

           />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>l̥
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are ways to solve this

> `First`

Make 2 columns in Gridlayout, It will make enough space for all the names.
    android:columnCount="3"

> `Second`
>   Make the text 2 liner and set its gravity in the centre. If you will make 
>   minLine 1 and maxLine 2, all the texts will not be aligned, so make minline 2 & maxline 2, It will make all the texts to cover the space equal to two lines.

```
              <TextView                         
                android:minLines="2"
                android:maxLines="2"/>
```

> `Third`

Use Recyclerview with GridLayoutManager approach